# ResourceManifest SetDependecies doesn't work in Orchard module

Tags: css, orchardcms

I Use Orchard 1.10.1 CMS. I have created a widget module in code. In the `ResourceManifest` file I added this code

```
public void BuildManifests(ResourceManifestBuilder builder)
    {
        var manifest = builder.Add();
        manifest.DefineStyle("ShareButtons").SetUrl("ShareButtons.css").SetDependencies("font-awesome.css");
    }
```

and in template cshml I added this code

```
@{    
Style.Require("ShareButtons");
}
```

Problem is in this case file `font-awesome.css` won't come in the page's source files.

what am I doing wrong here?

And when I use this code in template it works fine and `font-awesome.css` will come in the page's source files

```
@{    
Style.Include("font-awesome.css");
Style.Include("ShareButtons.css");
}
```

ps: In the Style folder of my module project I have `ShareButtons.css` and `font-awesome.css`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your setup is wrong. You must either register a depency yourself (just like your ShareButton-Style), or in your case use the correct FontAwesome resource from *Orchard.Resources*.

So your code would look like this:

`manifest.DefineStyle("ShareButtons")
   .SetUrl("ShareButtons.css")
   .SetDependencies("FontAwesome");`

Here's the setup of FontAwesome you're requiring as dependency from Orchard.Resources:

```
namespace Orchard.Resources {
    public class FontAwesome : IResourceManifestProvider {
        public void BuildManifests(ResourceManifestBuilder builder) {
            var manifest = builder.Add();
            manifest.DefineStyle("FontAwesome").SetUrl("font-awesome.min.css", "font-awesome.css").SetVersion("4.4.0").SetCdn("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css", "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css", true);
        }
    }
}
```